# Java Error: array required, but java.lang.String found

Tags: java

So after a long time spending time on this program I have finally managed to get this program to compile. After that hard work, it suddenly won't run the program. Sure it compiles just fine, but for some odd reason the program just doesn't run. It keeps saying, "run Period." I'm stressing out a lot right now, can somebody help me?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Period
{

  private static String phrase;
  String[] alphabet = new String [26];
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;
    int[] letter = new int [27];
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence with a period at the end.");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    userInput.toLowerCase();
  }

  public void Sorter(String newPhrase)
  {
    phrase=newPhrase.substring(0,newPhrase.indexOf("."));
  }

  private int charToInt(char currentLetter)
  {
    int converted=(int)currentLetter-(int)'a';
    return converted;
  }

  private void writeToArray()
  {
    char next;
    for (int i=0;i<phrase.length();i++)
    {
      next=(char)phrase.charAt(i);
      sort(next);
    }
  }

  private String cutPhrase()
  {
    phrase=phrase.substring(0,phrase.indexOf("."));
    return phrase;
  }

  private void sort(char toArray)
  {
    int placement=charToInt(toArray);
    if (placement<0)
    {
      alphabet[0]="1";
    }
    else
    {
      // here is one of the places it mainly occurs.
      alphabet[placement]=alphabet[placement]+1;
    }
  }

  public void entryPoint()
  {
    writeToArray();
    displaySorted();
  }

  private void displaySorted()
  {
    for (int q=0; q<26;q++)
    {
      System.out.println("Number of " + (char)('a'+q) +"'s: "+alphabet[q]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing, to run this?

Comment: @DavidWallace What do you mean?

Comment: `it suddenly won't run` is not mean anything. What exception you got?

Comment: Well, you're not running your program.  Because your program itself doesn't print "run Period".  So what are you actually doing?  Typing something at a Windows command line that you think runs your program?  Choosing a menu option from your IDE that you think runs your program?  Double-clicking a shortcut somewhere that you think runs your program?  What are you physically doing, that you THINK is running your program, which actually ISN'T?

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm using doctor java right now and  I made this code. I'm trying to make it tell me to enter a sentence, but instead of that it just says "run period", which is the program I created, and doesn't do anything that I programmed it to do.

Comment: Well, the first thing that your program tries to do is to wait for you to enter an integer.  Did you do that?  Perhaps it's still waiting?

Comment: I think u are trying to count number of alphabets in a sentence. Right ? I have modified ur code to some extent. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon `;` at the end of this line

`String[] alphabet = new String [26]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are **trying to count number of alphabets in a sentence which ends with a dot (.)**. So to do this I have made some modifications to your program see below

**Modified Code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Period {

    private static String   phrase;
    String[]                alphabet    = new String[26];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        int[] letter = new int[27];
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence with a period at the end.");
        //      int number = keyboard.nextInt();
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        userInput.toLowerCase();
        Period period = new Period();
        period.Sorter(userInput);
        period.entryPoint();
    }

    public void Sorter(String newPhrase) {
        phrase = newPhrase.substring(0, newPhrase.indexOf("."));
    }    

    private int charToInt(char currentLetter) {
        int converted = (int) currentLetter - (int) 'a';
        return converted;
    }

    private void writeToArray() {
        char next;
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            next = (char) phrase.charAt(i);
            sort(next);
        }
    }

    private String cutPhrase() {
        phrase = phrase.substring(0, phrase.indexOf("."));
        return phrase;
    }

    private void sort(char toArray) {
        int placement = charToInt(toArray);
        if (placement < 0) {
            alphabet[0] = " 1";
        } else {
            // here is one of the places it mainly occurs.
            alphabet[placement] = alphabet[placement] + 1;
        }
    }

    public void entryPoint() {
        writeToArray();
        displaySorted();
    }

    private void displaySorted() {
        for (int q = 0; q < 26; q++) {
            System.out.println("Number of " + (char) ('a' + q) + "'s: " + alphabet[q]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a sentence with a period at the end.
Hello World.
Number of a's:  1 
Number of b's: null
Number of c's: null
Number of d's: null1
Number of e's: null1
Number of f's: null
Number of g's: null
Number of h's: null
Number of i's: null
Number of j's: null
Number of k's: null
Number of l's: null111
Number of m's: null
Number of n's: null
Number of o's: null11
Number of p's: null
Number of q's: null
Number of r's: null1
Number of s's: null
Number of t's: null
Number of u's: null
Number of v's: null
Number of w's: null
Number of x's: null
Number of y's: null
Number of z's: null
```

I have modified it to some extent. Now you can change it according to your requirement.

Note the input doesn't contains any `a` in sentence. Instead of displaying `1` in-front of `h` it showing in-front of `a`. So figure out what you are trying to do & how do want to generate the result.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out a little video tutorial on DrJava.

How exactly are you telling/making DrJava to run your program? Are you typing `run Period` ?

Try `java Period` instead.

Comment: R u giving answer or asking more clarification on question ? This should be a comment instead of answer.